# kafka-connect losing plugin configuration sometimes on abrupt restart of the node

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

This is the docker image we use to host docker-connect with the plugins

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.3.1

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java

# JDBC-MariaDB
RUN wget -nv -P /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/ https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/java/connector-java-2.4.4/mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar

# SNMP Source
RUN wget -nv -P /tmp/ https://github.com/name/kafka-connect-snmp/releases/download/0.0.1.11/kafka-connect-snmp-0.0.1.11.tar.gz
RUN mkdir /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp && tar -xf /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp-0.0.1.11.tar.gz -C /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp/
RUN mv /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp/usr/share/kafka-connect/kafka-connect-snmp /usr/share/java/
```

Now for some reason, when the node is restarted or shutdown abruptly, the plugin configurations are lost and unable to find any plugins.

Could someone please point out where might be the problem or steps to verify what is going wrong?

PS: I am unable to get the logs of any kind, due to some strict policies

Comment: Where's your Kafka broker hosted? Is that also on Docker?

Comment: yes, but in this setup the kafka connect is say few miles away in customer premises and its connecting to kafka broker via vpn tunnel.

Comment: Do you see the topics used by Kafka Connect to persist config being populated by Kafka Connect? Are you using the same group.id each time you launch it?

Comment: So it has the same group id always, and there has been no loss of the topics (not sure about this though because the developer did not check this thoroughly)

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ it's kinda hard to help here if you have no logs and you're not sure if the developer checked or not. Kafka Connect in distributed mode uses Kafka to persist its data. If the data's lost, then ergo something's up with your Kafka. Without any logs from Kafka Connect or Kafka, there's not much more to say.

Comment: Totally understand, I was more expecting the answers like “ok I have seen this before if you have configured in this”. But ok can I ask another question. Can the connectors be configured via env variables passed when launching docker? Or curl is the only way?

Comment: That's a new question :) If you post a new question I will answer it there

Comment: Fair. I was tempted to ask with less of text to type :) But here is the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424781/can-the-kafka-connectors-be-configured-via-env-variables-passed-when-launching-d